# D flip-flop frequency divider

Tags: digital-logic, integrated-circuit, flipflop

I'm using a transmission gate base DFF to build a simple frequency divider.

It worked, but I'm getting some weird waveform at some intermediate nodes and the power consumption is high too (11 μW). Could anyone be kind enough to provide some insights on this problem?

Here is the testbench, I'm using 1.8 V VDD and a 100 kHz clock.

[image: testbench]

Here is the DFF schematic:

[image: DFF]

Here is the waveform, you can see I have some weird staircase-like waves in some nodes.

[image]

Comment: You may have hold-time problems. Try using 3 inverters between Q and D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved. It turns out that I build my transmission gate wrong, and they didn't turn on and off properly.